# LINUX CENTOS 6.3 - 14:Pycurl Error 77 - Yum repository error

Tags: linux, centos

I have a new install of Centos 6.3 64 bit and receive this error when I try to do a yum erase of any httpd.

> Could not retrieve the mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
>   14: PYCURL ERROR 77 - "Problem with the SSL CA Cert (path? access rights?)"
>   Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: Have you done any basic troubleshooting like verifying network settings are correct, you can ping the gateway, you can resolve mirrorlist.centos.org, you can ping the external IP? I would post the output of the following commands: `ip addr`, `ip route`, `ping mirrorlist.centos.org`.

Comment: Look at this RedHat issue. Seems similar. http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/11877/fixes-centos-6.2-yums-metalink-certificate-errors

Answer (score 2):

it is possible your /etc/pki/tls/certs/ is messed up. Back up all files in there first, and then download new certificate bundle, as described [here](http://eric.lubow.org/2011/security/fixing-centos-root-certificate-authority-issues/):

```
curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Comment: ...and once yum works again, reinstall the ca-certificates package.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on CentOS6

```
mkdir /usr/src/ca-certificates && cd /usr/src/ca-certificates
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/ca-certificates-2015.2.6-65.0.1.el6_7.noarch.rpm
rpm2cpio ca-certificates-2015.2.6-65.0.1.el6_7.noarch.rpm | cpio -idmv
cp -pi ./etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.* /etc/pki/tls/certs/
```

Say yes to override.

To check :

```
curl -vvv https://www.unixy.net
```